# CakePHP 4 Query: I don't need created_at as FrozenTime, string is enough

Tags: cakephp, query-builder

Sometimes when I get data from database, i want data as array - method disableHydration() does it.
But timestamp fields (in the database) are still returned as objects FrozenTime.

Is it possible (and how) to turn off the automatic replacement of timestamp fields with objects of the type FrozenTime, when i don't need it?

$query->find()->disableHydration()->first();

returns:
(...)
'created_at' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) id:0 { },
'updated_at' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) id:0 { },
(...)

It would be enough for me:
'created_at' => (string) '2023-01-01 12:00:00',
'updated_at' => (string) '2023-02-02 12:00:00',

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello under the required table i.e. /src/Model/Table || /Entity , open your table / entity php file and under initialize function insert

```
$this->getSchema()->setColumnType('created_at', 'string');
```

That should help resolve this. so far this was the only way I could find after going thru the source files. I had to do this in other to create the needed JSON Objects for my project, without creating a for/foreach loops and rebuilding my nested / InnerJoin Models.